# Metric functions such that image of a closed ball is dense in a closed ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathcal{M}, d_{\mathcal{M}})$ and $(\mathcal{N}, d_{\mathcal{N}})$  be two metric spaces and $f : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$ a metric function (Lipschitz with constant $1$), i.e., we have $d_{\mathcal{N}}(f(x), f(y)) \leq d_{\mathcal{M}}(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathcal{N}$.

Have the functions satisfying the following condition been studied before?
The condition is: For any $\varepsilon > 0$, $x \in \mathcal{M}$ and $y \in \mathcal{N}$, such that $d_{\mathcal{N}}(f(x),y) \leq \varepsilon$ there exists a $z \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $d_{\mathcal{M}}(z,x) \leq \varepsilon$ and $$d(f(z),y) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$

Instead of $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ I we might alternatively require that there is a $\delta < \varepsilon$ ($\delta$ depending on $\varepsilon$ and $x$) such that $d(f(z),y) \leq \delta$.

If I am not mistaken this condition implies that, given $x$ and $\varepsilon$, the image under $f$ of the closed ball $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(x,\varepsilon)$ is dense in $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(f(x),\varepsilon)$. And if all these images of balls are dense then the condition is satisfied. So that is an alternative way of stating the condition.

So, have there been places where such conditions have come up?